# Android Canvas draw a multiple frame Image

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an image with different frame to be displayed, like the following:

[image: Multiframe gif]

As you can see that image has three frames, the full heart, half heart and empty space.

Now i need to only one frame of the three. I'm just wondering if there is a method to do that using a single gif in android sdk. 
For example in several language there is a method like:

```
canvas.drawImage(xpos,ypos,xwidth,xheight,gifx,gify,gifwidth,gifheight)
```

where gifx,gify,gifwidth,gifheight are the coordinates and size of the selected frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i answer myself, i just found a solution.

In order to draw a multiframe image the following method can be used:

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

Where:

- *Bitmap bitamp* is the Bitmap resource obtained with BitmapFactory.decodeResource (or via your preferred method).
- *Rect src* is the frame to be shown (it can be null)
- *Rect dst* rhe rectangle that the bitmap will be scaled/translated to fit into (it can be null)
- *Paint paint*  used to draw the bitmap (it can be null)

Another way (*that i didn't tested*) could be using *BitmapRegionDecoder* first of all a new instance of the object must be created using BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(...)
and then the selected region of bitmap to be shown could be obtained with the method:

```
public Bitmap decodeRegion (Rect rect, BitmapFactory.Options options)
```

Where rect is the selected region to be shown. For more info on BitmapRegionDecoder: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html